# How to submit displayed div based on dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

I have these two divs and a dropdown. I am able to display divs based on the dropdown selection. By default on page display I am displaying option1 in dropdown and div1. My problem is when I select option2 and enter details in div2 and submit page my dropdown value is stays correct but my div goes back to div1 and shows div1's validation messages to user. How to make displayed div and its values as is on page page submit?

```js
$('#purpose').on('change', function () {
    if (this.value == '1') {
        $("#div1").show();
         $("#div2").hide();
    } else {
        $("#div1").hide();
         $("#div2").show();
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Customer", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {

<select id='purpose'>
    <option value="1">Div1</option>
    <option value="2">Div2</option>
</select>
<div id='div1'>DIV 1 Details
       <input type='text' class='text' name='div1' />
    <br/>
</div>
<div id='div2' style='display:none;'>DIV 2 Details
       <input type='text' class='text' name='div2' />
    <br/>
</div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-tertiary" id="buy">Buy </button>
  }
  </div>
```

Comment: Are you using a model for your form or just posting the values directly to your action?

Comment: Cant you just reset the div selected and dropdown on submit?

Comment: I am using Model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your model to see what the value of Purpose is and show the correct div and option based on it

```html
<div id="main">
  @using (Html.BeginForm("Customer", "Home", FormMethod.Post)) 
  {
    <select id='purpose'>
      <option value="1"@(Model.Purpose == 1 ? " selected" : string.Empty)>Div1</option>
      <option value="2"@(Model.Purpose == 2 ? " selected" : string.Empty)>Div2</option>
    </select>
    <div id='div1'@(Model.Purpose == 2 ? " style='display:none;'" : string.Empty)>DIV 1 Details
      <input type='text' class='text' name='div1' />
      <br/>
    </div>
    <div id='div2'@(Model.Purpose == 1 ? " style='display:none;'" : string.Empty)>DIV 2 Details
      <input type='text' class='text' name='div2' />
      <br/>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-tertiary" id="buy">Buy </button> 
  }
</div>
```